# How do I use 'or' & 'and' properly in python

Tags: python

I've only started learning to program a few days ago and I chose python as my starting language. I'm in the process of making a basic calculator with 4 operators to choose between. I want to make it so that if you input a character that is not one of these: + - * / then it would not try to calculate, but print 'Invalid operator' instead. The calculator works on 3 human inputs; a (first number), operator, b (second number). 
Things I've already tried:

```
if not operator == '+' or '-' or '*' or '/'
    print('Invalid operator')
```

```
if not operator == ('+' or '-' or '*' or '/')
    print('Invalid operator')
```

So, only if the first operator is used will it not print 'Invalid operator', no matter the order. If any of the other three show 'Invalid operator' after the answer if printed. An answer on what I've done wrong and how to come about fixing my code would be greatly appreciated. Also an explanation on how things like this work for future reference would be cool too, since I haven't followed any online courses, I've just been using python documentation and stack overflow.

Comment: "or" isn't distributive, you have to write "not (operator == '+' or operator == '-' or ...)" and so on or use "in" as shown by Manoj.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `in` operator. Example:

```
if operator not in ['+', '-', '*', '/']:
    print("Invalid Operator")
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, didn't know that the `in` keyword existed. Thanks for help!

Comment: That's great!. Could you please accept the answer in that case.

Comment: good answer, can be simplified further to `operator not in '+-*/'` as long as you are testing only 1 character at a time, i.e. you dont want to test and accept `+-` because this is a substring test.

Comment: This will work, but it will be at the cost of clarity.

Answer (score 2):

In Python `or` and `and` is pretty basic. What `or` does is, the program executes the next line of code if one of your func is true. For an example:

eg: if the operator is '+' or '-' or '*', it knows that the line is true because it has + **or** - **or** *

What `and` does is it checks if all the variable are true. For an example:
eg: if person has hand **and** legs **and** body **and** head, the person is a human. It is true only if **all** the vars are true. Get it? If you want more explanation, try to google it.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this practically speaking is to use the `in` operator.

```
if not operator in ('+', '-', '*', '/'):
    print('Invalid operator')
```

If you *really* want to use `or`, you'd have to repeat the first half of the condition for every case:

```
if not operator == '+' or not operator == '-' or not operator == '*' or not operator == '/':
    print('Invalid operator')
```

You were also missing a `:` at the end of the first line of your `if` statement. You need to add the colon.

Comment: Oh, didn't realise i needed to repeat the not operator part for each or, good to know. And about the `:` i missed, that was just an error I made in the post. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @TheSalmonn no problem! Just FYI, you've seen at least three uses of the `in` operator here: I used it to check membership in a tuple `('+', '-', '*', '/')`, the accepted answer checked a list `['+', '-', '*', '/']`, and a comment checked a string `"+-*/"`. All of these will work (they may have better or worse performance, depending on the number of options). As long as the object you're using `in` on has the `__contains__` method, it will work. https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.contains